# Passing different list of methods to be called on listener event

Tags: java

I'm currently using an 3rd-party library  to load images,data asynchronously.
I pass a listener to that method and when the loading\download completed an event is passed to my listener and I start to use him. for example:

```
 getMainDownloader.getImagesLoader().loadImages(new IListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void loadingCompleted() {

                       //calling methods that uses this asset
                         method1();
                         method2();

                        }
                    }, ImagesList.get(0), ImagesList.get(3),ImagesList.get(5));
```

the listener Interface:

```
public static interface IListener {
    public void loadingCompleted();

}
```

In my code I have a lot of places where I should download those assets above, and call to different methods - `method5(),method12()`... on `loadingCompleted()`, so I copy the code above and each time change the methods what create a duplicated code.

Is there a technic to set one method for loading those assets and some how to pass the methods (method1()...) I want to be called in  `loadingCompleted()` ?

Comment: try java8 and method references

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an anonymous class you could use a "real" or nested class:

```
private static class MultiImagesListener implements IListener() {
    private final String imageId;
    public MultiImagesListener (String imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadingCompleted() {
        // use this.imageId to decide which methods to call...
        if (IMG_ID1.equals(imageId)) {
            method1();
            method13();
            method27();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Every time you pass an instance of your listener to the `loadImages`-method, you should pass a different argument to the constructor in order to distinguish the listener-instances:

```
getMainDownloader.getImagesLoader().loadImages(new MultiImagesListener(IMG_ID1);
getMainDownloader.getImagesLoader().loadImages(new MultiImagesListener(IMG_ID2);
```

Comment: Its a good approach if all the methods are the same, but some of the methods will use parameters that cant be declared in the class scope, they nee to be transferred to. also this will create a method with a lot of if-else statements...I want something more genericlly

Comment: If you have a nested (non-static) class, you can access the variables from the surrounding class-instance. So there should be no need to transfer them to the IListener in advance.
Since `loadingCompleted` has no arguments, IMO you have to distinguish the listener calls by passing some information at construction-time of the listener. Instead of this simple "String-approach" you could use enums/switch or if objects are available to distinguish, you could use the visitor-pattern.